# Null pointer dereference prevention

Tags: c, null-pointer

Why `p && *p` prevents null pointer dereference? 
How can I use the expression to prevent the dereference?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I use the expression to prevent the dereference?" ? Seems `p && *p` itself is an arbitrary example of how you might be able to prevent a null pointer dereference.

Comment: As I see, it's a condition but I cannot realize in why it should be true in case `p!=NULL`

Comment: Oh, probably I forgot that in C any Nonzero value is true in Boolean logic

Answer (score 3):

From C Standard#6.3.2.3p3

> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Footnotes
>
> 66) The macro NULL is defined in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.

Logical `AND` operation `expr1 && expr2` employs short-circuiting behavior. With logical short-circuiting, the second operand, `expr2`, is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand, `expr1`.
That is, `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `0` (false).

If `p` is a `NULL` pointer then it will be evaluated as `0` and due to short-circuiting behavior of `&&` operator `*p` will not be evaluated. Thats how `p && *p` prevents null pointer dereference.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
    p    &&   *p   
    |          |
   first     second 
   operand   operand
```

first `p` is performed that means if `p` is `NULL` then it won't do `*p` as logical AND `&&` operator property is that if **first operand** is `false` then don't check/evaluate **second operand**, hence *it prevents null pointer dereference.*

The fact that `p = NULL` means `p` is pointing to `NULL` hence one shouldn't do `*p` as it causes segmentation fault. For e.g

```
int *p = NULL;
if (!p ) {
  fprintf(stderr,"p is NULL, can't do further opertaion with p\n");
  exit(0);
}
else {
   /* further processing with p i.e p is valid and *p is not zero */
}
```

Comment: Well, if `p = NULL` then we go into else statement with NULL pointer, so no prevention

Comment: Yes true . I put  the check reversely. My bad. I will edit as soon I have my system.

Comment: I was playing around with that example and I noticed that if we set `int x = 0; int *p = &x;` then the code considers p as null-pointer. So, if we point to a variable the value of which is 0 at the moment, then we cannot work with the code further